# Converting JSON array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am attempting to use the Newtonsoft JSON library to parse a JSON string dynamically using C#. In the JSON is a named array. I would like to remove the square brackets from this array and then write out the modified JSON.

The JSON now looks like the following. I would like to remove the square bracket from the ProductDescription array.

```
{
    "Product": "123",
    "to_Description": [
        {
            "ProductDescription": "Product 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Desired result

```
{
    "Product": "123",
    "to_Description": 
        {
            "ProductDescription": "Product 1"
        }
}
```

I believe I can use the code below to parse the JSON. I just need some help with making the modification.

```
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"output.json"));
```

Comment: So you're saying that the array always contains 1 object, and you want to move the object out of the array and for it to replace the array, so that you only have that 1 object as the value? You **know** that there will always be 1 object in the array? Not 0? Not 2? Not more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create classes for this task.  You can modify your object like this:

```
// Load the JSON from a file into a JObject
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"output.json"));

// Get the desired property whose value is to be replaced
var prop = o1.Property("to_Description");

// Replace the property value with the first child JObject of the existing value
prop.Value = prop.Value.Children<JObject>().FirstOrDefault();

// write the changed JSON back to the original file
File.WriteAllText(@"output.json", o1.ToString());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/M83zv3

Answer (score 1):

The `to_Description` property starts off as `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` and you want to take the first element from the `List`.

So, given 2 classes

```
public class Source
{
   public string Product {get;set;}
   public List<Dictionary<string,string>> To_Description{get;set;}
}


public class Destination
{
   public string Product {get;set;}
   public Dictionary<string,string> To_Description{get;set;}
}
```

You could do it like this:

```
var src = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Source>(jsonString);
var dest = new Destination
{
    Product = src.Product,
    To_Description = src.To_Description[0]
};
var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dest);
```

Note: You might want to check there *really is* just 1 item in the list!

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vxqumd

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
public class EntityDescription 
{
  public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
   public string Product { get; set; }
}

public class Source : Entity 
{
   [JsonProperty("to_Description")]
   public EntityDescription[] Description { get; set; }
}

public class Target : Entity 
{
   [JsonProperty("to_Description")]
   public EntityDescription Description { get; set; }
}

var raw = File.ReadAllText(@"output.json");
var source = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Source>(raw);
var target = new Target { Product = source.Product, Description = source.Description.FirstOrDefault() };
var rawResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(target);
```

**Update** For dynamic JSON

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"output.json"));
var newjObject = new JObject();
foreach(var jToken in jObject) {
  if(jToken.Value is JArray) {
    List<JToken> l = jToken.Value.ToObject<List<JToken>>();
      if(l != null && l.Count > 0) {
          newjObject.Add(jToken.Key, l.First());    
             }
       } else {
          newjObject.Add(jToken.Key, jToken.Value);
       }
    }

   var newTxt = newjObject.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses. There will only be one object in the array. Apologies, but I didn't mention that the code needs to be dynamic. I want to read in the JSON and pass in any array to be converted, not just the one I had provided as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to convert the actual and desired output to classes and manipulated the input json.. this will help in the maintenance in future

First defined the model

```
    public class ToDescription
    {
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    }

    public class ActualObject
    {
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public List<ToDescription> to_Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChangedObject
    {
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public ToDescription to_Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Inject the logic

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"Product\": \"123\",  \"to_Description\": [     {        \"ProductDescription\": \"Product 1\"    }  ]} ";

        ActualObject actualObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActualObject>(json);
        ChangedObject changedObject = new ChangedObject();
        changedObject.Product = actualObject.Product;
        changedObject.to_Description = actualObject.to_Description[0];
        string formattedjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(changedObject);
        Console.WriteLine(formattedjson);
    }
```